# Problem with norms over $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, normed-spaces

> Let $\|\cdot\|$ be a norm over $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $\|e_1\|=\|e_2\|=\|e_1+e_2\|=1$, where $e_1, e_2$ are the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Show that $1≤\|e_1-e_2\|≤2.$

Now I can say that a norm with this conditions can be

$$
\|x\|=\sqrt{x_1^2-x_1x_2+x_2^2} \quad \text{or} \quad \|x\|=\sqrt{\left(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}\right)^2+3\left(\frac{x_1-x_2}{2}\right)^2}
$$

With both of these formulas I obtain $\|e_1-e_2\|=\sqrt3$ that indeed is $1≤\sqrt3≤2$.

Is this enough to be proved? What else can I consider?

Comment: That's not enough because you proved it for particular norms satisfying the condition. There can be (and are) more that satisfy it. So you cannot use any explicit form of the norm unless you have a proof that any such norm has a given expression (of whose existence I doubt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be solved by using the triangle inequality (which holds for any norm),

$$ \| a + b \| \leq \|a\| + \|b\|.$$

To show that $\| e_1 - e_2 \| \leq 2$ is straightforward application of the triangle inequaltiy,

$$ \|e_1 - e_2\| \leq \|e_1\| + \|-e_2\| = 2. $$

Observe that $e_1 - e_2 = 2e_1 - (e_1 + e_2)$ and then apply the reverse triangle inequality,

$$\|a\| - \|b\| \leq \|a - b\|$$

so

$$ \|e_1 - e_2\| = \| 2e_1 - (e_1 + e_2)\| \geq \|2e_1\| -  \|e_1 + e_2\| = 1. $$

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not correct, since we are dealing with an arbitrary norm here.

Note that $\lVert e_1+e_2\rVert\leqslant\lVert e_1\rVert+\lVert e_2\rVert\leqslant1$ and that\begin{align}2&=\lVert 2e_1\rVert\\&=\bigl\lVert(e_1+e_2)+(e_1-e_2)\bigr\rVert\\&\leqslant\lVert e_1+e_2\rVert+\lVert e_1-e_2\rVert\end{align}and that therefore$$\lVert e_1-e_2\rVert\geqslant2-\lVert e_1+e_2\rVert=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use $x_1-x_2=2x_1-(x_1+x_2)$ and the (reversed) triangular inequality.